# Explicit example of second Borel–Cantelli lemma

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Consider the probability model $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ and $P$ is the uniform measure on $[0,1]$.

Let $E_1, E_2, \dots$ be a sequence of independent events in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $P(E_n) = 1/n$.

Since $\sum P(E_n) = \infty$, by the second Borel–Cantelli lemma ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)),
$$
P(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty E_n) = 1.
$$

My question is:

**Is there any explicit example of such $E_n \subset [0,1]$?**

The most famous example of independent events on $[0,1]$ is the dyadic intervals:
Define

$D_1 = [0, 2^{-1}]$

$D_n = 2^{-1}D_{n-1} + (2^{-1}+2^{-1}D_{n-1}) $

$(D_n)_{n =1}^\infty$ is a sequence of independent events. However, for this example, $P(D_n) = 1/2^n$.

Is there any explicit example for $P(E_n) = 1/n$ ?

Comment: Just take an infinite sequence $X_n$ of independent random draws from $\Omega$ and let $E_n$ be the event $X_n\in [0,1/n]$.

Comment: @AlexB.That needs an explicit measure-preserving map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^\infty$, to answer the question as it is... Otherwise, take the canonical map from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}^\infty$ given by dyadic expansion, but then it would be hard to match $P(E_n)=1/n$ exactly (while having it approximately is easy).

Answer (score 9):

All irrational numbers in $(0,1)$ have unique representation as $\sum_{k=2}^\infty c_k/k!$, where $c_k\in \{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$. 'Digits' $c_k$ are independent, so you may choose the events $E_n$ as '$c_n=0$', for example.

Comment: That's a nice one

Comment: Simple and elegant

Answer (score 2):

Construction of such an example essentially amounts to an explicit decomposition of the unit interval $(\Omega,P)$ into a product of probability spaces. For instance, one can take an isomorphism between $(\Omega,P)$ and its infinite countable product by itself $(\Omega,P)\times(\Omega, P)\times \dots$. [Since $(\Omega,P)$ is a countable product of the dyadic space $\{0,1\}$ endowed with the uniform measure by itself, an explicit rearrangement of binary digits will then provide a required isomorphism.] Now, as it was suggested in Alex.B's comment, you just take in each of the multipliers a set of any measure you like.

Answer (score 0):

It  is awkward to construct an event of prob 1/17, e.g. out of dyadic, or even decimal digits.  As you want a  borel cantelli example in the unit interval, why don't you change your probabilities instead to make the point the same but the construction easier. Make e.g. $E_{17}$ a set of probability $[1000/17]/1000 = .058$.  Then your event might be decimal digits 49 -51  when placed in that order are a number  < 58.

Comment: It is not so awkward. Say, consider the minimal $k$ for which not all the digits from $(8k+1)$-st to $(8k+8)$-th are zeroes. The probability that the dyadic number formed by these 8 digits is divisible by 17 equals $1/17$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be any sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables such that $P(X_i = x)=0$ for all $x$. Such sequence can be built on the universe $[0,1]$ itself because any Borel standard space with a non-atomic probability measure is isomorphic to $[0,1]$ together with the Lebesgue measure. Define
$$
E_n = \{\omega \mid \forall \, k <n, \, X_k(\omega) < X_n(\omega)\}.
$$
If the event $E_n$ occurs, we say that there is a record at time $n$.
A standard exercice in probability theory asks to show that the $E_n$
are independent and that $P(E_n) = 1/n$. By Borel-Cantelli, this implies that there are infinitely many records almost surely.